# How to avoid that the Parameter Pane Area in Drill-Through Report is hidden

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that via a text box property action triggers a drill-through report (and gives it two parameters (start date, end date)). That all works fine in the report designer, however after deploying the report on the server the pane in the drill-through reports is hidden. Is there a way I can change this behavior. Our users want the pane to be visible in the drill-through report.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above suggestion (doing Go to URL and adding rc:Parameters=false) is that the parameters get completely reset and are shown blank. With the normal linking back to the main report using Go to Report it is possible to maintain the last user-entered values in the parameter boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do what ykatchou says, and use the "jump to url" function. It would have been much nicer if Microsoft had added the option to hide or show the parameters on a drillthrough report, but they didn't 
:-(

http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/drillthrough-action-hides-parameters-11425.shtml

Answer (score 1):

my solution for this was to call subreports through URL.

SSRS 
MS SQL Server 2008 R2

inside a TEXTBOX
go to the text box properties (F4 or right click->properties)
go to action
set go to URL
set up the following code within the expression (the little Fx at the right):

```
="http://MYSERVER/ReportServer?/MY REPORT FOLDER/MY REPORT NAME&rc:Parameters=True&rs:Command=Render&TODAY="
& CStr(Fields!DT_0.Value)
& "&ENG=" & CStr(Fields!Employee_id.Value)
& "&DT_TO=" & CStr(Fields!DT_6.Value)
```

this is working here.
notice the 3 parameters

parameter 1 is called TODAY
parameter 2 is called ENG
parameter 3 is called DT_TO

Their values come from different datasets.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the Url (of the webservices server) &rc:Parameters=false

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx

Comment: Should that be "rc:Parameters=true"? The pane should be visible.

Comment: sure, it depends of your needs.